# Fastest canvas to ffmpeg method

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg, html5-canvas, p5.js

I have an Electron JS app where I draw to a canvas and then send each frame to ffmpeg to create a video. It works well, but performance is not great. This is how I currently do it:

- I have an image stream (new PassThrough) that is piped to my ffmpeg process
- When a frame is ready, I convert it to a blob with canvas.toBlob()
- I convert the blob to arrayBuffer
- And get a buffer with Buffer.from()
- I write the buffer to the image stream with .write()

I have measured the time each step takes and the bottleneck is, by far, canvas.toBlob

Is there a way to do this entire process or the toBlob step faster? I have looked into HTMLCanvasElement.captureStream() but I don't think I can pipe that to ffmpeg.

I'm using P5js for drawing. It does not seem like there is a way to draw (more) directly to a blob or buffer. Even p5.Graphics seems to draw to a hidden canvas https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Graphics

Thanks

Comment: don't strikeout half your post, delete the text if it doesn't apply, or rewrite it if it applies but needs to be changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to skip the blob conversion entirely. The raw image data from an HTML5 canvas is already available as a Uint8ClampedArray in RGBA format. `canvas.toBlob` does image encoding (by default to PNG) which takes a bunch of time, and then you waste extra time by converting that back to an arraybuffer. However, FFmpeg can be configured to take raw video in an uncompressed form, so the encoding and the roundtripping through blob and back to arraybuffer format is completely unnecessary (you'd need something like `-vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba -s <width>x<height>` in the command line options).

Get the right command line options for FFmpeg, and you should be able to use `CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData().data` and stream that directly to FFmpeg once per frame.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. However ffmpeg says the output file is empty. I have updated my question.

Comment: Ok. The problem was I was using "-f image2pipe" in my command instead of "-f rawvideo". Now it works but it's not faster than using toBlob. Will see if moving this to a worker makes a difference

Comment: I finally found the time to work on this again. I accepted the answer because this approach is faster in small test projects, like this comparison I created: https://github.com/JuanIrache/canvas-stream-test

The fastest option so far is running ffmpeg in a web worker.

However in my reals projects the original approach is still faster. Not sure why. Will keep trying